# BASIC to whatever language converter

Tags: basic

Is there a BASIC to some other programming language (Perl, Python, R, ...)?

Having in mind that BASIC once was very widespread - every PC had a BASIC interpreter and BASIC was even taught at schools - I would think there would be a converter from BASIC to some other language, but I could not find one.

I have been [mutilated](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd04xx/EWD498.PDF) before, and took me decades to recover. I don't want to experience this yet again. I am trying to convert an old program to R, but reading some 400 lines of BASIC code and finding 35 GOTOs is alreading taking its toll.

Comment: Language-to-language transformers are vanishingly rare, and the greater the difference in philosophy between two langauges, the more difficult it will be to convert between them even inadequately. BASIC is one of the languages that is philosophically different from just about anything modern, and absolutely should not be mechanically translated - especially as BASIC did nothing to discourage GOTO, which statement doesn't even have an equivalent in many modern languages. You're going to have to analyze the program, and rewrite it from scratch in your language of choice.

Comment: Also, any mechanical language conversion between two fundamentally different languages is going to generate code that's hard to read and modify, and often very repetitive, especially when GOTOs are involved. The end result would not be very useful in practice.

Comment: As I feared. Thanks Jeff Zeitlin and JJJ.

Comment: It can be done but it is not pretty. There is a BASIC to C++ emitter called QB64 which translates BASIC to C++ code in a directory \qb64\internal\source into a file main.txt which you might look at..

Answer (score 1):

There is a BASIC to C Translator called BaCon. It offers a modern BASIC style without the need to use GOTOs. It supports also functions for making GUIs.

https://www.basic-converter.org/

http://basic-converter.proboards.com/

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I was able to perform the manual translation, the only major hiccups were the nested and / or branching GOTOs.